# Imports dinâmicos em Javascript

Tags: javascript, react

Preciso importar dinamicamente os caminhos para os assets de uma aplicação, por exemplo:

`var cliente = clienteX`

`import ../../caminho/${cliente}/caminho/arquivo.less`

Não será mudado em tempo de execução, ele apenas puxaria de um arquivo de configuração, qual cliente ele puxará os assets, tendo em vista que o Core do sistema é o mesmo.

Pelo que pesquisei o `import` é estático, então queria alguma ajuda ou ideia de algum workaround para essa situação.

Edit 1: Exemplo de estrutura

- Sistema
- Clientes
- cliente 1

  - css

    - main.css
- cliente 2

  - css

    - main.css

Exemplo de imports:

`require ('../../Clientes/'+ cliente + '/css/main.css');`

`import ../../Clientes/${cliente}/css/main.css;`

Comment: Já tentou usar o `require`? Se você está usando o `babel`, ele tem suporte para o `require` no browser. Exemplo: https://github.com/pedrolaxe/js-terminal/blob/master/src/js/terminal/commands/index.js#L20

Comment: @GabrielKatakura Já tentei também e não rolou muito bem :/

Comment: Podes tentar usar o `path.resolve` combinado com o `__dirname`, dá um exemplo da estrutura de diretórios para ficar mais claro

Comment: @Sergio atualizei ali na pergunta

Comment: Os exemplos que colocaste foi o que tentaste e não funcionou?

Comment: @Sergio isso ai

Answer (score 1):

Você não consegue criar `imports` dinâmicos. Como você comentou, o `import` do javascript é estático, logo não aceita interpolação de `strings`.

O que você consegue fazer é usar o `require`.

```
require ('../../Clientes/'+ cliente + '/css/main.css');
```

ou

```
require (`../../Clientes/${cliente}/css/main.css`);
```

Devem funcionar. Caso não funcionem o seu erro deve ser outro. Consegue verificar se o `path` está correto? Se fizer o mesmo `require` estático com o caminho de um dos clientes ele funciona?

Exemplo:

```
require (`../../Clientes/cliente1/css/main.css`);
```

Nesse caso, consegue verificar se o valor da variável `cliente` está correto?

Caso não consiga importar estaticamente, verifique a configuração do seu compilador (`Babel`) para checar se não existe algum erro no `loader`.

Caso continue errado, consegue postar o log do erro no terminal?

Comment: Tentei com o require, mas igual não funcionou. Ele não retorna erro, simplesmente não importa. Fiz o require passando o caminho de um dos clientes e funciona. ai passei o nome do cliente pra uma variável e passei ela e ele não importou :/

Comment: Você consegue confirmar se ele realmente não está importando? Coloque um `body { background: #000 !important; }` no estilo importado só para validar que ele realmente não está sendo importado. Fez o teste importando sem a variável com o cliente1 no lugar? Caso continue dando erro, você consegue importar qualquer outro arquivo css no projeto? Para validar que não é um problema com o loader.

Comment: Sim, eu importando passando o nome do cliente direto ele importa e altera o css, se eu passar ele como variável ele não importa mesmo.

Comment: Consegue dar um `console.log` na variável? Para verificar que o valor dela é o esperado?

Comment: retorna a string do cliente mesmo hahaha. Parece que somente o fato de ter algo "variável" no caminho, faz com que ele não seja importado

Answer (score 1):

Você consegue fazer imports dinâmicos sim, porém, até onde eu sei, apenas consegue fazer com arquivos '.js'. Vamos lá, suponha que você tem um arquivo muito grande e, dependendo do clique do usuário, deve fazer algo que é exportado por esse arquivo. Se você importar ele durante a requisição da página, pode ser que seu carregamento fique lento e não tenha o comportamento desejado, para isso existem imports dinâmicos. A idéia é que você importa o arquivo, e de dentro dele usa as funções de são exportadas.

Use assim:

```
const file = await import('./caminho')
const something = file.exportedFunction()
```

https://javascript.info/modules-dynamic-imports

Comment: Por favor, adicione mais detalhes para expandir sua resposta, como um código que funcione ou citações de documentação.